# Display many to many relationships data with Thymeleaf in Spring Application

Tags: spring, join, thymeleaf, display

I have two entities: book and author. This is many to many relationships. I would like get the table with all columns of books with their authors and show them into a table using Thymeleaf in Spring Application.

Here Book class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="book", schema="booksloan")
public class Book{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private String title;
private String year;


@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {
                CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE
        },mappedBy = "book")
private Set<Author> author = new HashSet<>();

public Book() {
}

// getters and setters

}
```

And here Author class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Author", schema="booksloan")
public class Author{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id_author;
private String name;
private String surname;


@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
          name = "written", 
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_author"), 
          inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();


public Author() {

}

// getters and setters

}
```

I don't know if it is useful this Written class:

```
@Entity
public class Written{

private int id;
private int id_author;

public Written() {

}

// getters and setters

}
```

Here BookRepository interface

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Libro, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Written s JOIN Book l on s.id = l.id JOIN Author a on a.id_author = s.id_author", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Book> findWrittenBy();
}
```

In AppController class

```
@RequestMapping(value={"", "/", "/index"})
public String index(Model model) {
    List<Book> listBooksTest = bookService.findWrittenBy();
    model.addAttribute("listBooksTest", listBooksTest);

    return "indexUser";
    }
}
```

And here indexUser

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Books</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h1>Books list</h1>         
        <br />
        <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID Book</th>
                    <th>ID Author</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th>Name Author</th>
                    <th>Surname Author</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr th:each="book : ${listBooksTest}">
                    <td th:text="${book.id}">ID Book</td>
                    <td th:text="${book.id_author}">ID Author</td>
                    <td th:text="${book.title}">Title</td>
                    <td th:text="${book.year}">Year</td>
                    <td th:text="${book.name}">Name Author</td>                 
                    <td th:text="${book.surname}">Surname Author</td>

                    <td><a th:href="@{'/copy/' + ${book.id}}">View copy</a>

                    </td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here the error I get

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'id_author' cannot be found on object of type 'net.assignment.booksLoan.model.Book' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

Does anybody know how can I do this?

Comment: What does the table `Written` looks like?

Comment: In my database the Written table has two key "id" and "id_author" only, where id is the foreign key for id book. I don't know if it is correct, but I have created Written class too. I edited post to insert Written class too, but I'm not sure if this class is important or not to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

You know instead of wasting time (we hate wasting time, don't we) figuring out what particular query suits from which side of the entities, you could just combine the resulted columns into a custome model/class. Or in a similar way , just combine the intersected rows from `List<Book>` and `List<Author>` within the same controller and pass them to the view.

Your query ideally would be

```
@Query(value = "w.id, w.id_author, b.id, b.title, b.year, a.id_author, a.name, a.surname 
FROM Book b
INNER JOIN
Written w on b.id = w.id
INNER JOIN 
Author a on w.id_author = a.id_author ", nativeQuery = true)
public List <IntersectionResult> findAllIntersectedColumn ();
```

The thing is that your list's signature is *Book*, and you're expecting to also get the `name` and `surename` but they're not explicitly defined in the Book as fields eventhough they're related to one another through an *M-to-M* model. There's also a topic about the [*projection interface*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces) to retrieve a subset of attributes in relation that you can read on spring's doc.